# How to resolve couldnt set flutter sdk in local properties

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea

```
    Am using the geolocator in my app currently and after i run the app it generate a build exception of:
    
   

<!--This is the Error in console-->

     flutter.sdk not set in local.properties. Expression: (flutterSdkPath != null). Values: flutterSdkPath = null
```

for which i tried so many solutions
on previous articles but all count to anything resolving the problem.Please i need help and any will be appreciated

```
<!--This is the local properties-->

sdk.dir=D:\\flutter\\flutter_windows_3.3.10-stable\\AndroidSdk
flutter.sdk=D:\\flutter\\flutter_windows_3.3.10-stable\\flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1


I initial changed the path to D\:\\flutter\\flutter_windows_3.3.10-stable\\flutter but couldnt solve the problem,changed my GradleException to fileNotFoundException also produced the same problem
```